# Invalid null character in text to output

Tags: web-services, xml-parsing, jax-ws, woodstox

I'm trying to Pass some data process in the server side to the client through my WS.

But I'm getting this error:

```
    SEVERE: caught throwable
    javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid null   character in text to output
        at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.encode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:112)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.encode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:278)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.encodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:380)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.access$100(HttpAdapter.java:92)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:525)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:285)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:143)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:155)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:189)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:76)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:555)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid null character in text to output
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.writeCharacters(BaseStreamWriter.java:520)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.util.DOMUtil.serializeNode(DOMUtil.java:135)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.util.DOMUtil.serializeNode(DOMUtil.java:138)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.util.DOMUtil.serializeNode(DOMUtil.java:138)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.util.DOMUtil.serializeNode(DOMUtil.java:138)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.util.DOMUtil.serializeNode(DOMUtil.java:138)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.util.DOMUtil.serializeNode(DOMUtil.java:138)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.util.DOMUtil.serializeNode(DOMUtil.java:138)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.message.saaj.SAAJMessage.writeTo(SAAJMessage.java:365)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.encode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:109)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid null character in text to output
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.XmlWriter.throwInvalidChar(XmlWriter.java:538)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.writeCharacters(BufferingXmlWriter.java:453)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.writeCharacters(BaseStreamWriter.java:518)
```

This exception is thrown while sending the response back to the client.

in the client side this is the response:

```
ParseError at [row,col]:[1,11347]
```

But looking At this Its very difficult to find where is the error. Is there anyway that I can resolve this error.

Comment: and what did you are doing while the error show?

Comment: The service call is meant to do a calculation on the service side and return the answer. The error occurs when trying to send the response back to the client side

Comment: Did you ever find out what caused this ?

Answer (score 0):

As exception suggests, some String (character data value) in object you trying to write out contains null character (Unicode zero).
Beyond finding and fixing corrupt String value(s), you can also work around the problem by making Woodstox change such invalid character values. See [How to alleviate the infamous "Xml Invalid Character" problem with Woodstox](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2008/12/entry_106.html) .